# Convert Alamofire Request to URLSession Request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, codable, urlsession

I've this JSON response -

[image: json response]

I've followed [this blog](https://medium.com/fabcoding/creating-an-ios-place-picker-places-autocomplete-search-ui-using-mapbox-api-fba5c29958eb) to make api call and decode the response. Their code snippet for this -

```
func searchPlaces(query: String) {
        let urlStr = "\(mapbox_api)\(query).json?access_token=\(mapbox_access_token)"
        print(urlStr)

        Alamofire.request(urlStr, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseSwiftyJSON { (dataResponse) in
            
            if dataResponse.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(dataResponse.result.value!)
                if let myjson = resJson["features"].array {
                    for itemobj in myjson ?? [] {
                        try? print(itemobj.rawData())
                        do {
                            let place = try self.decoder.decode(Feature.self, from: itemobj.rawData())
                            self.searchedPlaces.add(place)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        } catch let error  {
                            if let error = error as? DecodingError {
                                print(error.errorDescription)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if dataResponse.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = dataResponse.result.error!
            }
        }
}
```

Here they take **each features item** by a for loop then decode that and append that in an array. **I want to **convert** this by using URLSession**. But this part they used **dataResponse.result** which is not available in URLSession -

```
 if dataResponse.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(dataResponse.result.value!)
                if let myjson = resJson["features"].array {
                    for itemobj in myjson ?? [] {
                        try? print(itemobj.rawData())
                        do {
                            let place = try self.decoder.decode(Feature.self, from: itemobj.rawData())
                            self.searchedPlaces.add(place)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
```

So how can I convert this dataResponse.result part using URLSession?

Codable structs (This is they used for alamofire request) -

```
struct Feature: Codable {
    var id: String!
    var type: String?
    var matching_place_name: String?
    var place_name: String?
    var geometry: Geometry
    var center: [Double]
    var properties: Properties
}

struct Geometry: Codable {
    var type: String?
    var coordinates: [Double]
}

struct Properties: Codable {
    var address: String?
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the goal. Both Alamofire and URLSession dataTask can return the same data, Alamofire even deserialized in several formats.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `URLSession` this is a possible solution:

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "https://YOUR_URL")!
let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

    // Check the response
    print(response)
            
   // Check if an error occured
   if error != nil {
      // HERE you can manage the error
      print(error)
      return
   }
            
   // Serialize the data into an object
   do {                
      let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(FullResponse.self, from: data!)

      //try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
      print(json)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         // pass data to main thread
      }

   } catch {
      print("Error during JSON serialization: \(error.localizedDescription)")
   }
})
task.resume()
```

You probably need to create a struct for the FullResponse.

Comment: That is not my problem. My problem is how can I take a part of JSON and then used that to docode using codable

Comment: Full response: `let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])` , just take the part of it you need.

Comment: `if let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) { `
                `let feature = jsonObject["features"]`
                `print(feature)`
            `}`

Got 'Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts' Error

Comment: Check /print the jsonObject.

Comment: jsonObject has the full response. How can I chop only features [response image is in the question] from it?

Comment: I would suggest to use the code of my answer but if you prefer to use JSONSerialization.jsonObject, you probably need to use `if let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {  let features = jsonObject["features"] print(feature) }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231051/discussion-between-lovo-and-mefahimrahman).